# Django CSRF failure when form posts to a different frame

Tags: python, django, iframe, django-csrf

I'm building a page where I want to have a form that posts to an iframe on the same page.  The Template looks like this:

```
    <form action="form-results" method="post" target="resultspane" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input name="query">
        <input type=submit>
    </form>

    <iframe src="form-results" name="resultspane" width="100%" height="70%">
    </iframe>
```

The view behind `form-results` is getting CSRF errors.  Is there something special needed for cross-frame posting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the problem has nothing to do with cross-form POSTing.  The template that displays the form needs to be rendered with `RequestContext` as in

```
return render_to_response('form_template.html',
        context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: What did you view look like before? I'm using the shortcut for `render_to_response`, which is `render` and getting csrf errors when I load my site in an iframe and attempt to perform a POST. @Leopd